# How refactor incrementing in scala?

Tags: java, scala, increment

I have a code like that:

```
var index = 0
var array: Array[String] = //initialized

functionOne(array(index))
index = index + 1
functionTwo(array(index))
index = index + 1
```

The idea is clear - I need to increment index each time when I get element from array. With java can simply write `index++` intead of duplicating `index = index+ 1` everywhere. Is there a pattern/api to refactor code above with scala?

Comment: You could use `index += 1`.

Answer (score 3):

If the use-case is to call a different function for each element of the array, then a neater solution is

```
var array: Array[String] = ??? // intialized
// as many functions as needed
val functions = Array(functionOne, functionTwo, functionThree);  

(array zip functions) foreach { case (el, f) => f(el) }
```

This is an example of a more general idea here that if you're not doing anything with the index value, just using it to access a collection, then probably there's a way of doing it that doesn't need the index at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking imperatively rather than functionally.  If you wanted to apply a function to each element in an array within Scala, then the idiomatic way of doing it is to utilise the map function, so that you have something like:

```
val elements = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
val results = elements map { x => x+4}
```

If you need to utilise the index of each element in your function call, then transform the array into an array (or sequence) of pairs using zip with index like this:

```
scala> elements.zipWithIndex
res0: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,4), (6,5))
```

Then you can apply a map again, this time applying a function which takes a pair rather than a single element:

```
scala> elements.zipWithIndex map { case (x,y) => (x, y*5) }
res2: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,0), (2,5), (3,10), (4,15), (5,20), (6,25))
```

or

```
 scala> elements.zipWithIndex map { case (x, y) => x*y }
 res3: Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 6, 12, 20, 30)
```

If you want to apply a different function per index, then just supply a different definition within the map closure:

```
scala> elements.zipWithIndex map { 
   case (0, y) => y + 45
 | case (1, y) => y + 5
 | case (_, y) => y
 | }
```

Comment: The quesrion about applying different function of array element. E.g. `functionOne` and `functionTwo` are different function calls.

Comment: In that case you would just use a different function definition within the map closure...one which alters depending on the passed in index...

Comment: The case-within-the-map is pretty ugly. If the OP wants to call one  function on first, a different on the second, and so on then better is something like `(array.toList zip List( functionOne, functionTwo,[etc.])).foreach(case (el, f) => f(el))`?

Comment: Yep - good point Paul.  That's cleaner and more readable really.

Answer (score 0):

Scala doesnot hav incremental operators. In place you can use `index+=1`. Please refer [Why no i++ in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520463/why-no-i-in-scala)

Comment: But there would be still two lines of code instead one line in Java.

Comment: @rtruszk, no there would be the same number of lines. In java, 2x `index++`. In Scala, 2x `index+=1`

Comment: @Paul No. In Java would be one line: functionOne(array[index++]) and in Scala two lines: functionOne(array(index))  and index+=1

Comment: Yes, you could write it in one line, but the OP didn't. So I don't see the two as equivalent. Anyway, messing with indexes at all isn't really needed. See my answer