# Is there a way to use ++ on Int in scala?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [++ operator in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992399/operator-in-scala)

I want to increment an `Int` variable in scala. But, because `Int` is immutable, I have to do this

```
var myInt: Int = 5
....
myInt = myInt + 1
```

which seems a little too complicated. What I would like to do is

```
var myInt: Int = 5
....
myInt++
```

however, since Int is immutable, I can't do this. Is there any solution? Because I can't be first who would want to use `++` on integer variable...

Comment: TL;DR create a custom increment function: `def inc(i:Int) = i+1`

Comment: try scala without var in most vases you won't need it anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `++` operator is not a language construct of Scala, and the desired behaviour cannot be achieved with a regular method definition. But Scala offers at least some syntactic help, in that a call `a += b` will be automatically expanded to `a = a + b` unless a direct method `+=` exists. Thus:

```
var myInt = 5
myInt += 1
```

Comment: `a+=1`, that's quite enough for me. Thanks!